# use execSQL or COMMIT to conclude a transaction

Tags: sql, delphi

What would be the right way to conclude a transaction ? :

```
Query.SQL.Add('START TRANSACTION;');
-----
-----
Query.SQL.Add('COMMIT;');
Query.ExecSQL;
```

or

```
Query.SQL.Add('START TRANSACTION;');
-----
-----
Query.ExecSQL; 
Query.SQL.Add('COMMIT;');
```

edit :
Or this way :

```
.......
.......
try
if not Database1.InTransaction then
Database1.StartTransaction;
Query.ExecSQL;
Database1.Commit;
except  on E : Exception do begin
Database1.Rollback;
```

Comment: The first one seems to be *better*. There might be even right way, but we need to know the library components and DBMS you are using.

Comment: Your either use the first option, or control the transaction via `T<Whatever>Connection` you use. the second option does not execute and the transaction is not committed to the db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally you have to control the transaction under try except to prevent errors from insert or update statements.. so I suggest
to use start transaction on tConnection and not on tquery under try except

```
try
  AdoConnection1.BeginTrans;
  ----
  ----
  query1.ExecSql;
  AdoConnection1.CommitTrans;
except
  AdoConnection1.RollbackTrans;
  ----- 
  // manage the exception after rollback
  ----- 
end;
```

Note:
It's very important to place RollbackTrans at the first line in the exception management, because any other code as showmessage or anything else could lock a part of database tables for other users

Comment: I would include code to capture (and log) the exception object, and if my code can not handle it, re-raise it

Comment: To get the exception has been raised I use this function:

`function GetStrException(ExceptObject: TObject; ExceptAddr: Pointer):String;
var
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of Char;
begin
    ExceptionErrorMessage(ExceptObject, ExceptAddr, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
    Result:=Buffer;
end;`

Comment: so in the exception section you have to get the error description usig this function, manage it then raise a new exception if you cannot handle the error, using `raise exception.create('yuor error message')`

Comment: `BeginTrans` should be outside the `try` block

Comment: why? @kobik In my opinion it doesn't really matter, but If you want to catch all the possible errors that the beginTranscation method should throw

Comment: b/c an exception could be raised in BeginTrans, and you RollbackTrans in *any case*. if BeginTrans raising an exception let the default exception handler handle it, or use another try block (which is IMO not needed).

Comment: Ok I agree with you, even if a BeginTrans could raise an exception when another transaction is started.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly it should go : try
if not Database1.InTransaction then
Database1.StartTransaction;
Query.ExecSQL;
Database1.Commit;
except  on E : Exception do begin
Database1.Rollback;

Comment: should not the query SQL be also out of the TRY block ?

Comment: @kobik I've seen the idea of begintransaction outside of the `try` block here as wellhttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction()